# What do I use now that BootstrapNotifier interface is deprecated in IBEACON?

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

What do I use now that BootstrapNotifier interface is deprecated in IBEACON?

> Ibeacon deprecated : 1) RegionBootstrap 2) BootstrapNotifier 3)
> BackgroundPowerSaver

is there any alternate solution or reference link?
I shared my full code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap


class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity(), BootstrapNotifier {
    private var regionBootstrap: RegionBootstrap? = null
    private var backgroundPowerSaver: BackgroundPowerSaver? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       // showNotification(this,"found beacon init")
        //enable beacon features///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        val beaconManager: BeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this)
        beaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()
        beaconManager.beaconParsers
            .add(org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"))
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false) // disable JobScheduler-based scans (used on Android 8+)
        beaconManager.backgroundBetweenScanPeriod = 0 // set the time between each scan to be 1 hour (3600 seconds)
        beaconManager.backgroundScanPeriod = 1100 // set the duration of the scan to be 1.1 seconds
        val region = Region("backgroundRegion", null, null, null)
        regionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, region) // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        backgroundPowerSaver = BackgroundPowerSaver(this) //This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

    override fun didEnterRegion(arg0: Region?) {
        Log.d("mybeacon", "i found a enter")
       showNotification(this,"found beacon enter")
    }

    override fun didExitRegion(region: Region?) {
        Log.d("mybeacon", "i found a exit")
       showNotification(this,"found beacon exit")
    }
    override fun didDetermineStateForRegion(state: Int, region: Region?) {}


    //............................................................
    fun showNotification(context: Context, message: String?) {

       
    }

}
```

**implementation :**

```
 implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.19.3'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library version 2.19+ introduces autowind APIs that make setting up beacon scanning much simpler, more intuitive and less prone to configuration errors.

In earlier versions of the library, auto-launch of an app on beacon detection was handled by the `RegionBootstrap` utility class, but as of 2.19 it is no longer necessary -- you simply start monitoring with `startMonitoring(region)`. The library sample code shows an example of how to start up auto-launch section of the [code samples](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

To start up beacon scanning in the background simply replace `regionBootstrap = RegionBootstrap(this, region)`  with this:

```
beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this)
beaconManager.startMonitoring(region)
```

Instead of the `BootstrapNotifier` interface, your class should implement `MonitorNotifier`.

While it is unrelated to the autobind API changes in 2.19, be aware that if you want the library to automatically launch your app on beacon detection, you must implement the above code in the `onCreate` method of a custom Android Application class and not an Activity as shown in the question.  If you don't care about auto launch, then doing this in an Activity class is fine.